# Relaxing Statistical Independence

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Given two random variables $x \sim X$ and $y \sim Y$, for finite sets just to keep thing simple, we say that they are independent if
$$
 \Pr[ x = x_0, \; y = y_0 ] = \Pr[x = x_0] \cdot \Pr[y = y_0]
$$
for every $x_0, y_0 \in X \times Y$ (In general one replace singletons with measurable sets of the respective space). For several applications I felt the need to define a relaxed notion of independence, that I called $\varepsilon$-independence and is satisfied if
$$
 I(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_0 \in X} \sum_{y_0 \in Y} \left| \Pr[x = x_0, \; y = y_0] - \Pr[x = x_0] \Pr[y = y_0] \right| \leq \varepsilon.
$$
For those familiar with the statistical distance it's easily proved that
$$
  I(x,y) = \sum_{x_0 \in X} \Delta(y_{|x = x_0}, y) \Pr[x = x_0]
$$
where $y_{|A}$ is the random variable such that $\Pr[y_{|A} = y_0] = \Pr[y = y_0 \mid A]$ for any event $A$ (all of this can be easily generalized for any probability spaces and in that languagge $I(x,y)$ is simply the distance between the joint distribution $(x,y)$ and the product distribution $x \times y$).

In my opinion the notion fits so well in the general theory that there has to be a reference. Can anyone point this out?

Comment: I suggest you to look the definition of mutual information $H(X) -H(X|Y)$. It is supposed to capture the same notion.(with $H$ the entropy function).